# BERT uses WordPiece, RoBERTa uses BPE

Tags: bert, transfer-learning, transformer, language-model, tokenization

In the original [**BERT**](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1810.04805.pdf) paper, section *'A.2 Pre-training Procedure'*, it is mentioned:

> The LM masking is applied after **WordPiece** tokenization with a uniform masking rate of 15%, and no special consideration given to partial word pieces.

And in the [**RoBERTa**](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1907.11692.pdf) paper, section *'4.4 Text Encoding'* it is mentioned:

> The original BERT implementation (Devlin et al., 2019) uses a
> character-level **BPE** vocabulary of size 30K, which is learned after
> preprocessing the input with heuristic tokenization rules.

I appreciate if someone can clarify why in the [RoBERTa](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1907.11692.pdf) paper it is said that [BERT](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1810.04805.pdf) uses BPE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BPE and word pieces are fairly equivalent, with only [minimal differences](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55416944/674487). In practical terms, their main difference is that BPE places the `@@` at the end of tokens while wordpieces place the `##` at the beginning.

Therefore, I understand that the authors of RoBERTa take the liberty of using BPE and wordpieces interchangeably.

Comment: Thank you @ncasas. Does that mean technically I can pre-train and fine-tune a RoBERTa based model with a WordPiece tokenizer? (I am using the Huggingface liblary)

Comment: Yes, you can pre-train a RoBERTa with a wordpiece tokenizer, and then fine-tune it with the same wordpiece tokenizer.